# How do I launch Tor browser on specific web page from command line?

Tags: command-line, tor-browser

I need a script to open Tor browser at specific web site.

Comment: I think the command would be similar to `firefox u.r.l` (where u.r.l is page URL).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you downloaded the tor browser from [torproject.org](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en) and installed it following the [Linux Instructions](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en#linux), then you can simply run the starter with a URL as an argument and it will open it:

```
./start-tor-browser.desktop google.com
```

If you don't want to use the `.desktop` file, run it directly with

```
./Browser/start-tor-browser --detach google.com
```

or using an absolute path (substitute `LANG` with your language code):

```
/path/to/tor-browser_LANG/Browser/start-tor-browser --detach google.com
```

Comment: What if the Tor Browser is already open? Then I get the error "Tor Browser is already running, but is not responding. To open a new window, you must first close the existing Tor Browser process, or restart your system."

Comment: @lefterav If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//askubuntu.com/questions/ask) button.